# Is there a total div alternative in Haskell prelude?

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for something which wraps the div into Maybe. I want to specifically know if there is a thing for it in prelude, since I'm working on a uni assignment, and we cannot use modules other than prelude. I can make a lambda, but why make a lambda if it already exists. Lambda in function composition looks ugly.

I've also realized that what i can do i guess is to use  `division <$> Maybe divisor`. Now that in turn makes me wonder if maybe a function to check equality and if equal return Nothing exists.

Comment: If there were such a function, what type would it have? Try looking for that type on Hoogle. (I don't find anything in `base`)

Comment: amalloy, I assumed it be Eq a => a -> a -> Maybe a, but yes i didn't find it on hoogle

Comment: You could always roll your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do your own:

```
-- does division, returns Nothing if divisor is zero
tdiv :: Integral a => a -> a -> Maybe a
tdiv x y
   | y == 0 = Nothing
   | otherwise = Just (x `div` y)

main = do 
    print $ 2 `tdiv` 1
    print $ 1 `tdiv` 0
```

Comment: How about `tdiv _ 0 = Nothing; tdiv x y = Just $ x ``div`` y`?

Comment: It's also kinda cute to use `guard`, IMO, since we're "guarding" that the denominator shouldn't be zero: `safeDiv num denom = guard (denom /= 0) *> pure (num \`div\` denom`)

Comment: Yes, i ended up using something similar - But i hoped i could saved couple characters by using some conveniently predefined thingy from prelude

Comment: Or even with `MonadComprehensions`: ``[ num `div` denom | denom /= 0 ]``

Comment: `div` also givs arithmetic overflow on `div minBound (-1) :: Int`